# I'm confused by how RegEx distinguishes between apostrophes and single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I’m trying to better understand RegEx and apostrophes/single quotes.
If I use this code:

```
const regex = /\b[\'\w]+\b/g
console.log(phrase.match(regex))
```

Then

```
let phrase = "'pickle'" // becomes pickle (single quotes disappear)
let phrase = "can't" // becomes can't (apostrophe remains)
```

I thought I knew what all regex do:

- `/text/g` means everything between the slashes and g means global, to
  keep searching after the first hit.
- `\b` is word boundary, spaces on each side
- `w+` means alphanumerics, and the '+' indicates it can be for more
  than 1 character
- `[\w\']+` means A-Za-z0-9 and apostrophe of any length.

But I'd like to get this:
`let phrase = "'pickle'" // becomes 'pickle' (with single quotes)`

What am I missing? I experimented with

```
const regex2 = /\b[\w+\']\b/g;
console.log(phrase.match(regex2))
let phrase = "can't"
```

But that becomes `["'", "t"]` ... why? I understand now that the `+` is after the `\w`, the `\'` stands alone, but why "t" and where did the "can" go?

I tried

```
const regex3 = /\b\'[\w+]\'\b/g;
console.log(phrase.match(regex3))
```

But I get "null". Why?

Comment: What do you mean by " `"'pickle'"` becomes pickle ", exactly? Where are the single-quotes disappearing? You're only using `string.match(regex)` instead of doing a regex-based replacement. `match` returns an array containing matched groups. Shouldn't your `let phrase = ...` lines go before the `const regex` line?

Comment: thanks for replying! this is my first StackOverflow question. If `let phrase = "'pickle'"` the RegEx match takes out the single quotes to return `pickle`. I want it to return `'pickle'`. It does, however, retain the apostrophe when I `let phrase = "don't"` ... I'm just using the `.match` to understand better how RegEx works, this isn't actual usable code. Same with the order, it should be the `let` statement, then the `const` statement, and then the `console.log`

Comment: You're mistaken on what `\b` means. It has nothing to do with spaces. It means a transition from "word character" (alphanumeric, plus underscore) to non-word character (anything else).

Comment: yes! I see it now. thank you! that test engine provided by Dave also helped. I misunderstood the `\b` and putting them next to `\'` screwed things up because `'` is also a boundary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is basically **"How do I get word boundaries including apostrophes"**. Right?

If so, then the regex you have `/\b[\'\w]+\b/g` explicitly looks for `\b` for boundary which will *match a non word character (like space or apostrohpe) followed by a letter or viceversa*. Like this: https://regex101.com/r/7Pxsru/1, (I added a few more words so that the boundary is clearly seen)

If you would like to get "'pickle'" and "can't" then simply don't look for `\b`, like this `/[\w+\']+/g`, see the demo: https://regex101.com/r/FNjlEq/1

The two regexes you propose mean the following:

- `/\b[\w+\']\b/g`: Look for a boundary letter then any word letter any number of times (note that this has no effect since it is inside a `[]`) OR an apostrophe then a boundary.
- `/\b\'[\w+]\'\b/g`: Look for a boundary letter by an apostrophe and any word any number of times (note that there is no need to be inside a `[]`) then followed by an apostrophe and a word boundary.

Comment: Apostrophes are different than single quotes though. For example, I tested your regex with the word can’t and it did not work. I tested with the word can't and it worked fine.

1) can’t does not work 
2) can't works

Answer (score 1):

```
const regex2 = /\b[\w+\']\b/g;
```

In this one, since the `+` in inside of `[]`, it is matching a literal `+` character, so you're searching for a word boundary, followed by either a single alphanumeric character, a `+`, or a `'`, following by a word boundary.

You probably want:

```
\b(\w+|\')\b
```

which looks for a word boundary, followed by either at least one alphanumeric character or a single quote.

It would probably help to look at regex101 so you can see what the regex is actually doing: https://regex101.com/r/aJPWAB/1